# No implementation found for void org.telegram.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava(boolean)

Tags: android, android-ndk, native, telegram

In latest telegram source code in [github](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) removing prebuilt libraries and when download and debug source code get this error

> No implementation found for void org.telegram.tgnet.ConnectionsManager.native_setJava(boolean) (tried      Java_org_telegram_tgnet_ConnectionsManager_native_1setJava and Java_org_telegram_tgnet_ConnectionsManager_native_1setJava__Z)

how fix it?